# Trying to Set a Custom Field Value on a Customer, from a Custom Record Field

Tags: search, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm struggling with a script that is supposed to:

1. Search for a list of Customer's
2. Get a couple of Field Values, one of which is used in the next Search, the other is the ID
3. Search for a list of Custom Records, the criteria being one of the fields I just fetched
4. Get a field value
5. And use the Customer ID fetched earlier to assign the Custom Record field value to a Custom field on the Customer.

But it is dropping out on the second search, saying that it is returning "undefined" due to invalid Search Criteria. I'm assuming that the field I get from the first search is not working in the Criteria of the second search?

My code is below - is it an obvious one (as usual), or is it literally the wrong way to go about this?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/search'],

function getShipSuburbId(search) {
  function execute() {
    var customerSearchObj = search.create({
        type: "customer",
        filters:
            [
                ["custentity_store_shipping_suburb","isnotempty",""]
            ],
        columns:
            [
                search.createColumn({
                    name: "entityid"
                }),
                search.createColumn({name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"})
            ]
    });
    var custSearchResult = customerSearchObj.runPaged({pageSize: 1000});
    log.debug({title: "customerSearchObj result count", details: custSearchResult.count});
    var custNumPages = custSearchResult.pageRanges.length;
    var custAllResults = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < custNumPages) {
        custAllResults = custAllResults.concat(custSearchResult.fetch(i).data);
        i++;
    }

        return custAllResults;
        for (var j = 0; j < custAllResults.length; j++) {
            var currentRecord = custAllResults[j].getValue({
                name: "entityid"
            });
            var shipSub = custAllResults[j].getValue({
                name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"
            });
};

var shipSubIdSearch = search.create({
   type: "customrecord_suburb",
   filters:
   [
      ["name","is",shipSub]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({
         name: "internalid",
         summary: "MAX",
         label: "Internal ID"
      })
   ]
});

        var allSubIdResults = shipSubIdSearch.runPaged({pageSize: 1});
    log.debug({title: "shipSubIdSearch result count", details: allSubIdResults.count});
    var subNumPages = custSearchResult.pageRanges.length;
    var subAllResults = [];
    var m = 0;
    while (m < subNumPages) {
        subAllResults = subAllResults.concat(allSubIdResults.fetch(m).data);
        m++;
    }
          return subAllResults;
          
    for (var k = 0; k < subAllResults.length; k++) {
    var shipSubId = subAllResults[k].getValue({
        name: "internalid"
    });
};
      var setSuburbId = currentRecord.setValue({

                    fieldId: 'custentity_shipping_suburb_id',

                    value: shipSubId

                });
      return setSuburbId;
  }
  return {
    execute : execute
  };

});
```

**NEW CODE BELOW**

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/search', 'N/record'],

function getShipSuburbId(search, record) {
  function execute() {

      var customerSearchObj = search.create({
          type: "customer",
          filters:
              [
                  ["custentity_store_shipping_suburb", "isnotempty", ""]
              ],
          columns:
              [
                  search.createColumn({
                      name: "entityid"
                  }),
                  search.createColumn({name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"})
              ]
      });     // The first search, which draws a list of Customers

      var custSearchResult = customerSearchObj.runPaged({pageSize: 1000});    // Run paged
      log.debug({title: "customerSearchObj result count", details: custSearchResult.count});
      var custNumPages = custSearchResult.pageRanges.length;

      var custAllResults = [];
      var i = 0;
      while (i < custNumPages) {
          custAllResults = custAllResults.concat(custSearchResult.fetch(i).data);
          i++;
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < custAllResults.length; j++) {
          var currentRecord = custAllResults[j].getValue({
              name: "entityid"
          });
          var shipSub = custAllResults[j].getValue({
              name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"
          });
          log.debug({title: "currentRecord", details: currentRecord});
          log.debug({title: "shipSub", details: shipSub});
          // I've left this "for" operation open for the next search - possible issue?


          var shipSubIdSearch = search.create({
              type: "customrecord_suburb",
              filters:
                  [
                      ["name", "is", shipSub]
                  ],
              columns:
                  [
                      search.createColumn({
                          name: "internalid",
                          summary: "MAX",
                          label: "Internal ID"
                      })
                  ]
          }); // Second search. This should only return one result each time it is run
          var subIdRun = shipSubIdSearch.run();
          log.debug({title: "subIdRun result count", details: subIdRun.count});

          var shipSubId = subIdRun.each(
            function (result) {
              log.debug({
                  title: "Fetch ID",
                  details: result.getValue({name: "internalid"})
              })
              return true;
          });
          log.debug({title: "shipSubId result", details: shipSubId});

          var myRecord = record.load({
              type: 'customer',
              id: currentRecord
          }); // Load the Customer record, based on the id fetched in the first search
          log.debug({title: "myRecord", details: myRecord});

          myRecord.setValue({

              fieldId: 'custentity_shipping_suburb_id',

              value: shipSubId

          }); // And set the value of the Custom field, based on value from second search

      }
  }
  return {
    execute : execute
  };

});
```

And screenshot of Execution Log on New Script:
[image: Screenshot of Execution Log]

Comment: You have several `return` statements which would terminate the `execute` function before it reaches the end.  The first is `return custAllResults;` on line 34 - before it even gets to the 'second search'.  Could you clarify what you mean by 'it is dropping out...'?

Comment: Hello @Krypton, appreciate your comment... I will give that a try
By dropping out, I mean it didn't appear to be executing any further than that second search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best way to approach multiple levels of searching, is to gather the results of each search into an array.
Once I have finished dealing with the results of one search, then process each element of the array one by one, whether that be searching, querying, editing, etc.

The advantages of this include:

1. If a scheduled script, this allows me to check the governance usage after the first search, and reschedule with the array of results as a parameter if necessary.
2. Handling other logic like sorting or formulas on the array elements, before continuing with other operations.
3. Potentially faster processing, particularly if you don't need to process any further operations on some results of the first search.
4. This is just personal preference, but it makes it easier to split elements of the script into separate functions and maintain readability and logical sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to edit some of your code to get your closer to the answer. I've left comments explaining steps you'll need to take.

Try this and let me know how it goes!

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/search', "N/record"], function (search, record) {
    function execute() {
        let customers = [];
        let storeShippingSuburbIds = [];
        let storeShippingSuburbId;

        let searchCustomers = search.create({
            type: "customer",
            filters:
                [
                    ["custentity_store_shipping_suburb", "isnotempty", ""]
                ],
            columns:
                [
                    search.createColumn({name: "entityid"}),
                    search.createColumn({name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"})
                ]
        });

        var pagedData = searchCustomers.runPaged({pageSize: 1000});

        pagedData.pageRanges.forEach(function (pageRange) {
            let page = pagedData.fetch({index: pageRange.index});

            page.data.forEach(function (result) {
                customers.push([
                    result.getValue({name: "entityid"}),
                    result.getValue({name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"})
                ])

                storeShippingSuburbIds.push(result.getValue({name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb"}));
                return true;
            });
        });

        /*
         * I think you want the search operator of anyof here.
         */
        search.create({
            type: "customrecord_suburb",
            filters:
                [
                    ["name", "anyof", storeShippingSuburbIds]
                ],
            columns:
                [
                    search.createColumn({
                        name: "internalid",
                        summary: "MAX",
                        label: "Internal ID"
                    })
                ]
        }).run().each(function (result) {
            storeShippingSuburbId = result.getValue(result.columns[0]);
        });

        /*
         * You'll need to use record.load() here or record.submitFields(), depending on a few things.
         * But, it won't work as it is because it doesn't know what the "current record" is.
         */
        let myRecord = record.load();

        myRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custentity_shipping_suburb_id',
            value: storeShippingSuburbId
        });

        myRecord.save();
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks @zerecees
The record I wanted to execute setValue on was the one resulted in the first search, hence the .getValue({ name: "custentity_store_shipping_suburb" });

Comment: @Krypton and zerecees
I've added a second section of code above, but it returns this error:
"name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["create(N/searchPaging)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/shipSubIdScheduled5.js:58)"]

and also:
"code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["create(N/searchPaging)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/shipSubIdScheduled5.js:58)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"170d247c-a39a-44d1-8b7d-7637fd14b081-2d323032302e30372e3237"

Comment: It looks like you're trying to import a custom module, `N/searchPaging`? Did you mean to just import `N/search`?

Comment: Is Paged search results not a standard operation?

Comment: Paged search is something you can only do under `N/search`, which is the only module for searching. `N/searchPaging` isn't a thing.

Comment: OK, I'm confused :) where have I used N/searchPaging? It appears in the error message and nowhere in my script

Comment: By chance are you online now? Hoping for a little back and forth. If not, no worries, I'm working on checking a few things too.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue actually starts at line 37. Can you copy-paste log.debug({title: "shipSub", details: shipSub}) in at line 45? Let me know what the results are.

Comment: over two weeks to reply, think I've set a personal record
Will add that in and let you know... probably Thursday AEST

Comment: Just tried that @zerecees, I've got another Module does not exist Error
```Error: MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/ACL/Update Customer Shipping Suburb.js","stack":[]}```

Comment: No worries. That means your file "Update Customer Shipping Suburb.js" is not in the /SuiteScripts/ACL/ folder path in your file cabinet. Do you know where that file is?

Comment: not sure that I've seen this go wrong before - all I had to do was add ".js" to the file name.
The first search and search results have worked - looks like you're right about the second search/line 47 - I'll post the error in the next comment

Comment: Error: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["create(N/searchPaging)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Update Customer Shipping Suburb.js:64)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["create(N/searchPaging)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Update Customer Shipping Suburb.js:64)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"c4a7f895-cee5-4b0d-a354-4106c4fff392-2d323032302e30382e3230","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}

Comment: Looks like we're getting close! Can you copy-paste line 64 from your IDE? Just want to make sure we're working on the same line. Thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry, it probably has changed - Line 64 is now ```var allSubIdResults = shipSubIdSearch.runPaged({pageSize: 1});  // Run paged```

Comment: Maybe I shouldnt be running Paged? Especially as I'm only expecting 1 result!

Comment: don't know if getRange would be better?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I would not use runPaged. Only use runPaged when you expect more than 4000 results. If you have to runPaged, try to run with {pageSize: 1000}, as changing pages is an expensive operation.

Comment: just gave getRange for the first time - I've replaced the "New Code" above with my current script - and new error message below - it has stopped at the getRange, with apprently a NULL value? so I'm assuming the search is returning zero results?

Comment: Error: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["getRange(N/searchObject)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Update Customer Shipping Suburb v2.js:65)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["getRange(N/searchObject)","execute(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Update Customer Shipping Suburb v2.js:65)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"79a74c0a-f28b-4baf-9a7b-d1b4dbfda795-2d323032302e30382e3234","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}

Comment: if its running the second search that's the issue, do you think run.each(results) would be a better method?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for my late reply. Yes, I would (almost always) use `search.run().each(function(results))`. The reason is because you really can get the results down to less than 4000 almost all the time. You just might have to think about it. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: sorry been offline for a while. With run().each I've got the advantage of doing that in two steps, so I did, with a log in between. But that log returned NULL, then it errored at "each".

Comment: So the problem is with my second search. When I replicate this search exactly in Netsuite, it won't let me select "Any Of" as a filter, it automatically changes it to "Has Keywords". So I tried "haskeywords" but that also returned NULL result. Then tried "is" but that obviously didn't change anything either. I don't know if this is actually the issue, but something's wrong with that search.

Comment: I've updated the "NEW SCRIPT" above and added a screenshot of the Execution Log.

Comment: Hey! Hope your NetSuite journey has been going well. I wanted to acknowledge your comments back, but also wanted to let you know it's going to take a minute to re-wrap my brain around the problem. I'll be sure to try though, and will get back to you either way with what I find. I check stack usually once a day. So, if you have any updates, let me know!
-zerecees

Comment: Just wanted to comment back I haven't looked at this yet. Sorry. busy past few days. Safe to expect a response this week, though.